# How to safely turn off USB-connected, ATX PSU powered 3.5" hard disk drives built as internal?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, power-supply, power-management

I have a bunch of internal, 3.5" HDDs which I connect them to my laptop using an adaptor which converts SATA/IDE to USB 2.0. I can choose the "Safely remove storage" option in Windows 10 and it removes the access to the drives, but the HDD itself still is powered on and if I cut the power to it, a bad noise of sudden power outage to the HDD can be heard.

I use an ATX PSU for powering up the HDDs and disconnecting the USB adaptor from the laptop doesn't power the HDD down, so the solution to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/424193/turn-off-drive-after-safely-remove) similar question doesn't apply here.

I'm wondering how are HDDs in PC are powered off without suddenly cutting the power when you shut the Windows down?

Answer (score 0):

The noise you're hearing is just the read/write heads parking, which they do to prevent damage to the disc platters. What you're hearing is normal behaviour for a mechanical drive.